# parallelization of image watermarking

Tags: image, matlab, parallel-processing

I  am working on the parallelization of image processing. My task is to perform image watermarking on many-core and multi-core in Matlab. So, anybody please tell me how to work on it. I am new for parallelization. please help me. thank you

Comment: Have you tried using parfor? https://de.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/decide-when-to-use-parfor.html

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1** ) define a watermark-image ( a file to import the <sub>( be it { RGBA | BW }-pixmap matrix )</sub> data for watermarking )

**Step 2** ) define a list of files to watermark ( the batch to process )

**Step 3** ) define a Matlab or Octave **`.m`** script, that will consume 2 parameters, one - the watermark-image, the other - the image to get watermarked. The script ought simply open either of these, one read-only, the other one r/w and shall add the water-mask ( details about blending are up to your style and/or taste ) to {up|down}-scaled (X,Y)-locations onto the image-to-get-watermarked, saving the result once having done so

**Step 4** ) define a GNU **`parallel`** script so as to process the queue ( given the Step 2 ) as-much-parallel as the local hardware platform permits, by passing the proper parameters ( Ref.: Step 3 + Step 2 + Step 1 ) to the GNU `parallel`-pipeline-of-work. For all relevant configuration details you will need and/or prefer, kindly read the `man parallel`

### Why?

Given the productivity of contemporary many-core CPUs and their L3/L2-cache sizes, the many-parallel work-units will get way more productive, than a single-image `parfor`-decorated mini-jobs ( where file-I/O will not get latency-masked and the single-process work-flow would not over-compete the `parallel`-operated many-images processing, as RAM and cores permit ).

Comment: thanks for your response. Will you please do one fever. You have any MatLab code for this problem statement bcoz I am new in MatLab. If you help me, its a lot for me.

Comment: StackOverflow Community policy is to express any and all ***thanks*** by voting a +1 ( that indicates the Question or the Answer is useful, interesting or has other value to the Community now and in future ) and by clicking an Accept-tick for the best answer provided to the original posted problem. **Do not hesitate to follow this Community standard**. We all learn the whole life. This Community helps a World and a lot to learn, yet has never been a *do-my-homework for free* site, has it been?